# Issues controlling a 10,1 capacitive panel with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

Some days ago I had the inestimable help of hcheung in this forum to help me find some libraries on github to control a capacitive panel with a HT5xx6 controller. The libraries and code are [here](https://github.com/hellange/arduino/tree/master/capacitive_7in_panel).

I have copied and created the libraries into a.h and .cpp files and placed where arduino IDE can find them and run the sketch. The startup works fine, meaning the panel is initialized.

However it doesn't give reliable data. Any time you touch the panel in a specific location it does not give a single set of coordinates, it sometimes give 2 or 3 set of coordinates and most of the time 15. This is as if the panel would detect 15 touches!

Even more issues: the coordinates are never the same in one fixed location. So the data is not reliable and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Has anybody gone through this experience before?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Take care.

Joan.

Comment: is your panel the capacitive type for certain?

Comment: Hi jsotola, yes it is. I have the TDS and it is clear. https://focuslcds.com/content/FT5X26.pdf. Thanks.

Comment: The ISR might be fired up multiple times during the touch. Can you try to switch to another library https://github.com/sumotoy/FT5206? This one allows you to set your own interrupt pin and disable the interrupt when the touch is detected, read the coordinates and check against old coordinates. Read the example codes provided.  For random coordinates issue, make sure your power supply can provide sufficient power (1A-2A), and you might want to add a 10uF capacity between Vcc and GND.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment. I have tried all the above indications and still have the same issue. I have uploaded 3 videos on youtube so you can see what is happening, maybe this helps:

Comment: Part 1 Video [https://youtu.be/UwGcfkD-O-Q] - Part 2 Video [https://youtu.be/80RHSga8HTM] - Part 3 Video [https://youtu.be/yidqZx6y918]